# Why does the compiler need that trait hint?

Tags: rust, traits

I had this code:

```
pub trait MiddlewareHandler: Clone + Send {
    //...probably unimportant for the question
}

#[deriving(Clone)]
pub struct Middleware {
    handlers: Vec<Box<MiddlewareHandler>>
}

#[deriving(Clone)]
pub struct Server{
    middleware: Middleware
}
```

This left me with the compiler yelling at me with:

```
src/server.rs:20:31: 20:37 error: the type `server::Server', which does not fulfill `Send`, cannot implement this trait
src/server.rs:20 impl http::server::Server for Server {
                                           ^~~~~~
src/server.rs:20:31: 20:37 note: types implementing this trait must fulfill `Send+Sized`
src/server.rs:20 impl http::server::Server for Server {
```

It took me ages to figure out I had to change `Vec<Box<MiddlewareHandler>>` to `Vec<Box<MiddlewareHandler + Send>>` so that the final code looks like this:

```
pub trait MiddlewareHandler: Clone + Send {
    //...probably unimportant for the question
}

#[deriving(Clone)]
pub struct Middleware {
    handlers: Vec<Box<MiddlewareHandler + Send>>
}

#[deriving(Clone)]
pub struct Server{
    middleware: Middleware
}
```

The code compiles now but I quite don't understand what exactly was the problem here. Why `+Send` in the `Vec` definition? I mean, the `MiddlewareHandler` trait does already implement `Send + Clone`. It looks rather superfluous to me.

Can someone share his wisdom with me why I had to change the code like that?

Comment: The error message is pointing to the `server::Server` trait? What is its definition?

Comment: the `server` struct is the one outlined in this example also I simplified it a bit. It's this: https://github.com/floor-org/floor/blob/static/src/server.rs#L14

The `http::server::Server` trait is defined as such:
https://github.com/floor-org/floor/blob/static/src/server.rs#L14

Comment: I'm interested in the trait, not the struct, since that's in the error message. :)

Comment: There is no other `Server` trait involved. `server::Server` is the `Server` struct.

Comment: `impl http::server::Server for Server` is a trait.

Comment: Yep `http::server::Server` is the trait: https://github.com/chris-morgan/rust-http/blob/master/src/http/server/mod.rs#L15

and `Server` is the struct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a bug, I filed [#15155](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/15155).

---

The "problem" is the `Send` restriction on the `http::server::Server`. The definition is

```
pub trait Server: Send + Clone {
```

meaning the implementee needs to be both `Clone` (which is satisfied because you have implemented `Clone` via `#[deriving(Clone)]`) and `Send`. The compiler automatically implements `Send` for types where the contents satisfies `Send` (this detail will be changing with [opt-in built-in traits](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/127): they will require explicit implementations too), unfortunately the original type is something like

```
pub struct Middleware {
    handlers: Vec<Box<Trait>>
}
```

which does not implement `Send` in general: there's no way for the compiler to know that the erased type in the `Box<Trait>` is `Send`able, e.g. it could contain an `Rc`, and so be unsafe to transfer into a different task.

The compiler needs to know more information, that is, it needs to have a guarantee that the internal type is `Send`, which can be provided by adding more bounds to the trait object: `Box<Trait + Send>`...

However, in this case, the `MiddlewareHandler` trait already *has* this `Send` bound as a supertrait (meaning the contents of the trait object have to satisfy `Send` already), so it's weird that the compiler isn't working out that `Box<MiddlewareHandler>` is `Send` (hence filing the bug).

Comment: Can't the compiler just add all implemented traits to all usages of `MiddlewareHandler` itself? Why does Rust want me to do that manually if the compiler could easily look up the `MiddlewareHandler` trait and add `Clone + Send` (in this case) everywhere where `MiddlewareHandler` is used?

Comment: I mean, this could be even added as a pre compile step, no? I'm probably oversimplifying but for me the rule seems to be simply: Add all implemented traits of `MiddlewareHandler`, so in this case, `Clone + Send` to all locations where `MiddlewareHandler` is used. In this case at `Vec<Box<Middleware>>`. So a pre compile step could convert `Vec<Box<Middleware>>` to `Vec<Box<Middleware + Clone + Send>>` automatically. No?

Comment: Yes it could do that, but the current behaviour is a bug; there's no rhyme or reason, it's just what was accidentally implemented. Maybe what you describe is the fix (however, there's no way a pre-compilation step could be used, unless you essentially parse Rust with a script to edit the files).

Comment: I'm just a bit confused because on one hand you agree it's a bug but at the same time you write *there's no way for the compiler to know that the erased type in the `Box<MiddlewareHandler>` is Sendable*. I probably have to re-read this more often. I'm really thankful you dedicate so much time to help me get started with Rust. I wish I could give something back.

Comment: @Christoph, oh, sorry, I meant for a general trait object. I'll clarify.

Comment: Thanks! Let me just repeat with my own words. Normally there is no need to implement the `Send` trait at all because the compiler can infer that by analyzing the type directly. For traits however it can't and that's why one needs to explicitly name  `Send` in the trait declaration. Normally, that should be all we should have to do. That we need to annotate the `Send` again in that property is indeed a bug that should be fixed. Is that correct?